# Angular: Inject an abstract dependency

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have an "abstract" service named EntityService. This service is specialized in others such as ExerciseService, FooService, etc. Other componente: DeleteModal has the EntityService as dependency. In order to create this modal I need to specify the dependency resolution but always I get the following error:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[EntityService -> EntityService -> EntityService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for EntityService!
```

```ts
export class ExerciseDetailComponent {

  constructor(public modalService: NgbModal) { }

  delete() {
    const customInjector = Injector.create({ providers: [{provide: EntityDeleteModalComponent, deps: [{provide: EntityService, useClass: ExerciseService}, AlertService]}] });
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(EntityDeleteModalComponent, { injector: customInjector });
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'DeleteModalExercise';
  }

}

export class EntityDeleteModalComponent {

  loading = false;
  @Input() id: string;
  @Output('action') eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    public entityService: EntityService<Entity>,
    public alertService: AlertService
  ) {}

  delete() {
    const subscription = this.entityService.delete(this.id)
      .subscribe({
        next: data => {
          this.loading = false;
          subscription.unsubscribe();
          this.eventEmitter.emit('deleted');
        },
        error: error => {
          this.loading = false;
          subscription.unsubscribe();
          this.alertService.error(error.message);
          this.eventEmitter.emit('error');
        }
    });
  }

  export class EntityService<T extends Entity> {
    // Code omitted
  }

  @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class ExerciseService extends EntityService<Exercise> {
     // Code omitted
  }
}
```

In additon I tried with a customUseFactory but with the same result:

```ts
export class ExerciseDetailComponent {

  @Input() exercise$: Observable<Exercise>;
  enableEdit = true;

  constructor(public modalService: NgbModal) { }

  delete() {
    const customUseFactory = (
      httpClient: HttpClient,
      alertService: AlertService
    ) => new EntityDeleteModalComponent(new ExerciseService(httpClient), alertService);

    const customInjector = Injector.create({ providers: [{ provide: EntityDeleteModalComponent, useFactory: customUseFactory, deps: [ExerciseService, AlertService] }]});
    console.log(customInjector);
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(EntityDeleteModalComponent, { injector: customInjector });
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'DeleteModalExercise';
  }

}
```

How should I declare the Injector in order to resolve ExerciseService when the dependency is EntityService?

Comment: Have you tried `{ provide: EntityService, useClass: ExerciseService }`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that in `deps` but not working. I guess the first injector provider should be `EntityDeleteModalComponent` because is the modal type I want load and this second provide its dependencies reslution, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I guess you tried it in a wrong way. It should be `Injector.create({ providers: [{ provide: EntityService, useClass: ExerciseService }, { provide: EntityDeleteModalComponent, useFactory: customUseFactory, deps: [EntityService, AlertService] }]})`

Comment: The error message displays: `ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[EntityService -> EntityService -> HttpClient -> HttpHandler]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHandler!`

Comment: Add parent provider and it should work `Injector.create({ providers...}, this.inj)`

Comment: That works like a charm! I added the current injector as parameter in the constructor and I passed it as parent. Thx.